# How to run before and after maven test

Tags: maven, junit

```
mvn test
```

I am looking to initialize certain resources before all test cases executed using maven test and also to destroy them after all test cases are executed.

I have looked into jUnit **@BeforeClass**, **@AfterClass**, **@Before** and **@After**, but none of them are helpful.

I have tried to use maven life-cycle phases i.e. pre-integration-test as below, but even in this case the expected Test case (TestPostgresqlEmbedded) doesn't get executed first.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>test-init</id>
        <configuration>
          <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
          <includes>
            <include>**/TestPostgresqlEmbedded.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>test-all</id>
        <configuration>
          <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want to create class fields or do you want initialise resources like databases?

Comment: @JFMeier I want to initialize and destroy certain Database resources at the start and end of it respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `integration-test` phase for tests with databases. Then you have `pre-integration-test` to set up your database resources, and `post-integration-test` to destroy them.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, but as I am not very experienced with maven plugin, would you mind to show me bit in detail how to use such goals ?